# rewriting an sql script to include mysql commands and not SQLPlus commands

Tags: mysql

what is the best way to replace SQLPlus commands with mysql commands if you are trying to produce a report form a certain sql query

```
setpagesize 66


setlinesize 75
```

what is the best way to replace this is mysql. I have searched all over the net and cannot find any replacement. Also i am setting my title as

```
ttitle center 'EOMData(U), 2

column year heading "Year" formatt 999
column month heading 'Month' format 99
column day heading "day" format 99

select year,month,day from TB_EOMData order by year,month ,day;
```

it claims that setpagesize is an undelcared variable. Is my syntax correct for generating a report from a table named EOMData?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a program OTHER than the mysql command line client. The mysql command line client is entirely unsuitable for producing reports in the way that SQLPlus does.

Comment: unfortunaley i am limited to mysql command line. I have tp produce this report from a script that already exits and we have chosen mysql as our database

Comment: any suggestions you may have perhaps